# Underrealm Lich vs. Dredge

Tags: magic-the-gathering

No doubt, [Underrealm Lich](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=452961) is cool. Still I am wondering, how it interacts with [dredge](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Dredge), such as on [Life from the Loam](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=89001).

As both are replacement effects, I should be able to choose which happens, shouldn't I?

Asking for a [friend](https://scryfall.com/card/ddj/45/jarad-golgari-lich-lord).

Comment: I'm curious what interaction between dredge and Underrealm Lich you see that involves putting something "on top" of anything else. The existing answer seems to be correct, but if you can elaborate on your intention then a more detailed answer could be possible.

Comment: "On top" seems to imply you think the stack is used, but that's not the case. You apply one of your choice. (Then if still applicable, you apply the other.)

Comment: "On top" as in colloquial speech for "apply first".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both dredge and [Underrealm Lich](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnderrealm%20Lich%5d)'s ability are replacement effects. As such, you can choose which one you want to apply when you would draw a card.

> 616.1. If two or more replacement and/or prevention effects are attempting to modify the way an event affects an object or player, the affected object’s controller (or its owner if it has no controller) or the affected player chooses one to apply [...]